# com.apple.PressAndHold

Tags: mac-mini

My mac mini has been having a major problem.... basically becomes so slow that it's inoperable. When this happens and I click Command/option/ESC an item comes up in the force quit window that is labeled com.apple.PressAndHold. I do this when a window that says "You are running out of Application memory, close unused applications".... That is when I have literally only the finder open. When I force quit the com.apple.PressAndHold, the computer starts operating fine....

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this Terminal command to disable the PressAndHold option, which enables you to press characters down to get diacritical marks (accented characters.) `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` .